# How to open a network/file related webpage from a website itself

Tags: html

I have the following markup from my webpage(say test.html):

```
<html>
<body>
    <a id="link1" target = "_new" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Go to Yahoo</a>
    <a id="link2" target = "_new" href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
    <a id="link3" target = "_new" href="file://///server01/localWebPage.html">Go to Local webpage</a>
 </body>    
<html>
```

This will open a tab/window (and reuse hence the _new target) and it works when opening the webpage via File|Open|locate to test.html location. However when it's run using the web server (eg IIS). Running this via http://localhost/test.html, will not work for the localWebPage.html.

Any suggestion to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: probably not the problem but in your example the third link has same id than the second.

Comment: thanks updated, but yes not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want exactly but if you want to open a page in new tab/window, use the `target="_blank"`, if however, you want it to open in the same window, just leave out the `target="_blank"` part from the links.